# "Fair" Integer Average

Tags: language-agnostic, average

I have a need to get the average of a number, but not in decimal form, I need it in "fair" integer form. I don't know if that's the best way to explain it, so here's some examples.

Example:

```
51 / 4 = 12.75
```

But I need something more along the lines of:

```
51 / 4 = 13,13,13,12
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In what fields is the latter notation commonly found? I've never seen it before, but yet I find it strangely intriguing.

Comment: Suppose you had `50 / 4 = 12.5`. Is the corresponding "fair integer form" `13,13,12,12`, `13,12,13,12`, just `13,12`, or something else? Also for `51 / 7`, that's five at 7 and 2 at 8, but where in the list would you like the 8s to appear? Together or evenly spaced?

Comment: @Steve Jessop So long as they appear, order doesn't matter; And there should be `q` values for `p/q`.

Comment: good, everyone's answers are right then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
int base = floor( dividend / divisor );
int with_one_more = dividend MOD divisor;
```

The result would be `with_one_more` entries that are equal to `base+1`, and `divisor-with_one_more` entries that are `base`. In your example, `dividend`=51, `divisor`=4. This makes `base`=12, and `with_one_more`=3.

Answer (score 7):

Using programmatic integer division first, then use Modulus to find the remainder.
Here's an example:

Relying on integer division destroying your remainder.

> 99 / 5 = 19

Then use Modulus to find the remainder

```
99 % 5 = 4
```

Then increment four numbers...

giving a list of

```
20 20 20 20 19
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, for x / y, that would be a list that contains number (x div y) + 1 as often as (x mod y) times , and it contains number (x div y) as often as y - (x mod y) times.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your definition of "fair integer form", an algorithm to work this out could take the following form:

1. Determine the rational expression of the number (i.e. `p / q` for some `p`, `q`, if it's not already in this form).
2. Optionally reduce this to the most simplified form (this will generate the shortest possible output, though omitting this step will still generate "fair" lists)
3. Split this expression into a whole number and the remaining fractional part - so in your `51/4` case you'd have `12` and `3/4`.  Call these number `n` and `p/q`.
4. Output `q` numbers, the first `p` of which are `n + 1` and the remainder of which are `n`.

Answer (score 1):

If 51/4 returns the rounded down integer value, in this case 12, you know that the value falls between 12 and 13, thus take 51 modulus 13 which is 12.

```
x/y = z
x mod (z + 1) = w
```

your numbers are (y - 1) times z and w, for example:

```
63/4 = 15
63 mod (15 + 1) = 15
```

so the numbers are (4 - 1) times 16 and 15: 16, 16, 16, 15.